# No Root File Stystem is defined error when installing?

Tags: 11.10

Hey guys first time user and i dont know much here...

basically i took apart this old computer and reformatted the hard drive so its fresh, the install utility for ubuntu boots up and everything but when i get to the actual install page it gives me a window with

"No Root File Stystem is defined

so i try to hit some of the buttons but none of them are clickable...and i cant change the drop window on the bottom at all the one with /dev/sda

so and currently im just running it off the CD with the try it mode and trying to run the install from it when the OS is working

can anyone throw me some help? =/

Comment: Which option did you pick at the partitioning stage?

Comment: Ummmmmmm....i know what it is...but i dont think i did anything like that to it...i just hit format put the hard drive back in and got the OS to work off the CD

Comment: OK, which option did you pick at this stage: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1312973605.png? Since the hdd is free, I'd suggest to let the installer have it all - the second option.

Comment: Ive never seen that page....theres nothing on the hard drive atm. basically i just throw in the CD i burned and run it off the CD...when i try to install it, it shows me the error in the title and wont let me proceed. 

All i did to the hard drive was format it to default settings, i havent done any partitioning to it

Comment: Can you review the installation steps and specify exactly when you see the error: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall. Is it right after you click the Install button? If that's the case, I suspect the installer doesn't see the hdd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the option to erase the entire disk, then it is an installer bug and should be reported as such. Use the advanced method I have outlined as a workaround. If you are choosing to do a side-by-side, you can't, as you don't have another OS, and it would be pointless. If you are using the advanced partition option, delete your existing(formatted) partition, select the free space , click add *after selecting it*, and make an Ext4 filesystem. If it gives you a choice of mount point, select `/`. Otherwise, click OK to add the filesystem, click on it, click edit at the bottom *after selecting it*, and select the mount point to be `/`. Then, try to install.

Comment: Also, you may need to add a dummy filesystem(using gparted or disk utility) form the live CD(The demo system where it acts like a full installation)